# Slack no longer working in Iceweasel

Tags: iceweasel

I use Iceweasel (a libre/security-focused fork of Firefox). I use Parabola GNU/Linux and recently upgraded to Iceweasel version 108. Slack (a chat website) had worked with the previous version I had installed; however, now Slack does not seem to work. It gives me a page saying that my browser is no longer supported, despite the system requirements saying that it supports Firefox v.92 or above.

Does anyone know what has changed here? Is there any simple way to resolve this issue, so that I can continue using Slack with Iceweasel?

Comment: A useragent check is failing?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov ok, it's possible. How would I verify/rectify that?

Comment: about:config -> `general.useragent.override` put something more popular, e.g. `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov hmm ... Iceweasel doesn't seem to have that field. However, it has `general.useragent.compatMode.firefox`, which was set to 'false'. Enabling that does seem to allow Slack to work. Thanks very much!

Comment: Is slack a website? Question is not clear.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks for your comment - I have updated the question.